# How to iterate over nested arrays of objects and update their properties

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have data of the form

```
objects = [{
  ...someProperties,
  itemsOfInterest: [
    {
      ...someProperties,
    },
    {
      ...someProperties,
    },
    ...
  ],
},
{<same stuff>},
]
```

I want to go through each item in each `itemsOfInterest` and do some logic to add a field each one. I want this change to be reflected on the original object (or at least get back an object of the original shape).

I've tried something like:

```
_.map(objects, (object) => {
        const itemsOfInterest = _.map(object.itemsOfInterest, (itemOfInterest) => {
            itemOfInterest.newProperty = true;
            return itemOfInterest;
        });
        object.itemsOfInterest = itemsOfInterest;
    });
```

but that's pretty obviously wrong. I'm very new to JS so any help is appreciated! lodash usage is nice too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
objects.forEach(object=>{
  object.itemsOfInterest.forEach(item=>{
    if(true) item.newProp = 3; // put your own logic here
  })
})
```

Comment: You should always include some explanation of your code for the OP...

Comment: Nice, this did the trick. I was struggling with getting `forEach` just right.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `_.map()` method to iterate over the objects array and to iterate over the `itemsOfInterest` array. Then update the object as required:

```
const modifiedObjects = _.map(objects, (object) => {
  const itemsOfInterest = _.map(object.itemsOfInterest, (itemOfInterest) => {
    return _.assign({}, itemOfInterest, { newProperty: true });
  });
  return _.assign({}, object, { itemsOfInterest });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up using:

```
_.forEach(objects, (object) =>
    _.forEach(object.itemsOfInterest, (itemOfInterest) => {
        <setting logic here>
    })
)
```

Way easier than I was trying to make it!